# set dynamic date in json for spock test

Tags: java, json, date, groovy, spock

having below unit test case in spock

```
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = [DemoAppApplication])
class DemoAppIT extends Specification {

    @LocalServerPort
    int localServerPort

    def setup() {
        RestAssured.port = localServerPort
    }

    def 'test' () {
        expect:
        given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .body(Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/testdata/request.json").toURI()).toFile().text)
            .get('/hello')
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)

    }
}
```

below is request.json file

```
    {
      "trainingDate": "2022-08-10",
      "code": "ZMD",
      "name": "demo"
    }
```

here I want to populate trainingDate field as dynamically. dynamic value should be **current date + 10 days with the same above format**.

when I pass the request body to the `/hello` api, the date should passed as dynamically.

for example:

current date is `2022-07-01` and want to plus 10 days in request body everytime. with the `YYYY-MM-dd` format

any possibilities there to do this?

Note: **I'm maintaining request in file**

Comment: `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusDays(10)`?

Comment: edited my question and mentioned the format. any possibility of after reading the file also fine. at final request body must have current date + 10days with the yyyy-mm-dd format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `GString` with the code @OleVV already shared in the comment.

```
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = [DemoAppApplication])
class DemoAppIT extends Specification {

    @LocalServerPort
    int localServerPort

    def setup() {
        RestAssured.port = localServerPort
    }

    def 'test' () {
        expect:
        given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .body("""
    {
      "trainingDate": "${LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusDays(10)}",
      "code": "ZMD",
      "name": "demo"
    }
            """)
            .get('/hello')
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)

    }
}
```

---

Edit:

As OP really want to keep the original file, here a way to do it.
We have to replace the text in the file, there are always trade-offs on how to do it, either with placeholders or simple text replacement, or unmarshalling and marshalling of json.

To be as close to the original request, I'll go with text replacement.

```
def originalBody = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/testdata/request.json").toURI()).toFile().text
def newBody = originalBody.replace("2022-08-10", LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).plusDays(10).toString())
```

then just use `newBody` in the request.

Comment: I want to maintain the request in file. in that case, this is not working

Comment: @Remo I can't really recommend this, but I added a way to do it.

Comment: may I know why this is not recommended?

Comment: As there is no indication that the date in the file is special, the `request.json` could be changed without updating the test. Also, if the request is as short as shown here, I think that using a multiline string instead of reading from a file, makes it easier to understand what is going on.